# How to run Charles Proxy over Tor?

Tags: proxy, tor, charles-proxy

Following situation:

- intercepting web traffic with Charles Proxy works fine if i set the browsers http/https proxy to the port Charles is configured for (127.0.0.1:8888)
- surfing over anonymously over Tor works also fine if i set the browsers socks proxy to the one which Tor is configured for (127.0.0.1:9150)

Now i want to chain both proxies in the way, that i can intercept the web traffic of my browser with Charles while being anonymously over the Tor network. So i set my browsers http/https proxy to Charles and in Charles i set up the "external Proxies" to Tor.

But somehow this doesn't work. Do i have some misconceptions? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

1. Open command line (`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`) and type this command in the console window:
   `"C:\TorBrowserBundle\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe" --HTTPTunnelPort 8118`. Adjust path according to where your Tor Browser Bundle is located.
2. In Charles go to menu `Proxy→External Proxy Settings`
3. Select `Use external proxy servers` checkbox at the top
4. Clear `Web Proxy (HTTP)` and `SOCKS Proxy` checkboxes on the left side
5. Select `Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS)` on the left side
6. On the right side under `Secure Web Proxy Server` enter `127.0.0.1` and `8118`
7. At the bottom select `Always bypass external proxies for localhost` checkbox
8. Click `OK` to save changes
9. Try opening https://google.com/ in the web browser configured to use Charles (better in Incognito window to make sure that your Google account settings do not interfere with Google language detection by geo-location). You should see localized Google page in some random language.

**Explanations**

Tor provides SOCKS proxy out of the box. By default Tor uses port 9050. You mentioned port 9150. This is default port used by Tor Browser Bundle. So I assume you use Tor Browser Bundle. But specifying `SOCKS Proxy` settings in `External Proxy Settings` in Charles won't allow you to open websites via `https://` links. If you take a look at the [Charles documentation](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/external-proxies/), you might notice that only non-HTTPS traffic is being sent via SOCKS proxy. Quote (emphasis mine):

> If you have a SOCKS proxy Charles will use it for all **non-HTTP(S)** traffic such as for Port Forwarding.

So in order to chain Charles via Tor, you must use non-SOCKS proxy.

By the way, I was unable to open `http://` links via Charles when specified Tor as SOCKS proxy and disabled `Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS)`. No idea why.